# How i can get href from row

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, href

I do some telegram bot, and i need to get links from html.
I want to take href for Matches from this website https://www.hltv.org/matches

My previous code is

```
     elif message.text == "Matches":
        url_news = "https://www.hltv.org/matches"
        response = requests.get(url_news)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        match_info = []
        match_items = soup.find("div", class_="upcomingMatchesSection")
        print(match_items)
        for item in match_items:
            match_info.append({
                    "link": item.find("div", class_="upcomingMatch").text,
                    "title": item["href"]

            })
```

And i dont know how i can get links from this body.Appreciate any help

Comment: What exactly is the question? The div you are showing isn't complete, and you haven't said anything about your code.

Comment: just edited....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

You try to iterate over `match_items` but there is nothing to iterate, cause you only selected the section including the matches but not the matches itself.

#### How to fix?

Select the upcomingMatches instead and iterate over them:

```
match_items = soup.select("div.upcomingMatchesSection div.upcomingMatch")
```

Getting the `url` you have to select an `<a>`:

```
item.a["href"]
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


url_news = "https://www.hltv.org/matches"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url_news, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
match_info = []
match_items = soup.select("div.upcomingMatchesSection div.upcomingMatch")

for item in match_items:
    match_info.append({
            "title": item.get_text('|', strip=True),
            "link": item.a["href"]

    })
match_info
```

#### Output

```
[{'title': '09:00|bo3|1WIN|K23|Pinnacle Fall Series 2|Odds',
  'link': '/matches/2352066/1win-vs-k23-pinnacle-fall-series-2'},
 {'title': '09:00|bo3|INDE IRAE|Nemiga|Pinnacle Fall Series 2|Odds',
  'link': '/matches/2352067/inde-irae-vs-nemiga-pinnacle-fall-series-2'},
 {'title': '10:00|bo3|OPAA|Nexus|Malta Vibes Knockout Series 3|Odds',
  'link': '/matches/2352207/opaa-vs-nexus-malta-vibes-knockout-series-3'},
 {'title': '11:00|bo3|Checkmate|TBC|Funspark ULTI 2021 Asia Regional Series 3|Odds',
  'link': '/matches/2352092/checkmate-vs-tbc-funspark-ulti-2021-asia-regional-series-3'},
 {'title': '11:00|bo3|ORDER|Alke|ESEA Premier Season 38 Australia|Odds',
  'link': '/matches/2352122/order-vs-alke-esea-premier-season-38-australia'},...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

- All the match information is present inside a `<div>` with classname as `upcomingMatch`
- Select all those `<div>` and from each `<div>`, extract the match link which is present inside the `<a>` tag with class name as `match`.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_news = "https://www.hltv.org/matches"
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url_news,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
match_items = soup.find_all("div", class_="upcomingMatch")

for match in match_items:
    link = match.find('a', class_='match a-reset')['href']
    print(f'Link: {link}')
```

```
Link: /matches/2352235/malta-vibes-knockout-series-3-quarter-final-1-malta-vibes-knockout-series-3
Link: /matches/2352098/pinnacle-fall-series-2-quarter-final-2-pinnacle-fall-series-2
Link: /matches/2352236/malta-vibes-knockout-series-3-quarter-final-2-malta-vibes-knockout-series-3
Link: /matches/2352099/pinnacle-fall-series-2-quarter-final-3-pinnacle-fall-series-2
.
.
.
```