# How can i get all hrefs only from soup.find not find_all

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, href

I need get all hrefs from match_items, my code:

````
url_news = "https://www.hltv.org/matches"
response = requests.get(url_news)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
match_info = []
match_items = soup.find("div", class_="upcomingMatchesSection")
match_info.append(match_items.findAll("a", class_="match a-reset", href=True).item['href'])```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code produces a list of hrefs from the match_items div.
Each href is prefixed with '/matches/', which is what I believe you were after.

```py
url_news = "https://www.hltv.org/matches"
response = requests.get(url_news)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
match_items = soup.find("div", {"class": "upcomingMatchesSection"})
match_info = [item["href"] for item in match_items.findAll("a", {"class": "match a-reset"})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the result from [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69536178/14460824) or get it with this line of code:

```
[link['href'] for link in soup.select("div.upcomingMatch a")]
```

It is selecting all `<div>` that includes an `<a>` and with list comprehension syntax iterate over all results to create a list with urls.